How can I run a callback provided to custom component via tag attribute?
I'm developing a custom component which simply extends HTMLElement. I give the user the ability to specify one to three callbacks as tag attributes.
<my-component onopen="callback1()" onclose="callback2()" onabort="callback3()"/>
I can easily get the attributes in the connectedCallback()and attributeChangedCallback() methods. However, once I retrieve a callback, it's a simple string.
Let's say I save the callback in the private property #cb_close Now I need to call it: this.#cb_close( inp.value );
How can I do this?
